# Beautiful soup not loading new page after Selenium click

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The first page is loaded and parsed as expected but after the clicking on Next page, the BS4 does not get the new page from driver.page_source

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from urllib.request import urlopen as ureq
import random
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

def parse_html(pagesource, count):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    tables = soup.findChildren('table')
     # This will get the first (and only) table. Your page may have more.
    my_table = tables[0]
    table_body = my_table.find('tbody')
    all_rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
    # print (all_rows[0])

    for row in all_rows:
        print (count)
        count += 1
        try:
            path_body = row.find("td", class_="views-field-company-name")

            path = path_body.find("a")['href']
            company_name = path_body.find("a").text
            company_name = company_name.strip()
            print (company_name)

            issue_datetime = row.find("td", class_="views-field-field-letter-issue-datetime")
            # print (type(issue_datetime.find("time")['datetime']))

            issue_recepient_office = row.find("td", class_="views-field-field-building").string
            issue_recepient_office = issue_recepient_office.strip()

            # print (issue_recepient_office)


            detailed_description = row.find("td", class_="views-field-field-detailed-description-2").string

            if detailed_description:
                detailed_description = detailed_description.strip()
            else:
                detailed_description = ""    
            #print (detailed_description)
        except: 
            pass
    
url = 'https://www.fda.gov/inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/compliance-actions-and-activities/warning-letters'

driver.get(url)
count = 1
parse_html(driver.page_source, count)
    
for i in range(0,3):
    time.sleep(10)
    #print(driver.page_source.encode('utf-8'))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#datatable_next a'))).click()

    time.sleep(30)
    parse_html(driver.page_source, count)
        
driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
1
Ruth Special Food Store LLC
Foreign Supplier Verification Program (FSVP)
2
EarthLab, Inc., dba Wise Woman Herbals

3
Big Olaf Creamery LLC dba Big Olaf
CGMP/Food/Prepared, Packed or Held Under Insanitary Conditions/Adulterated/L. monocytogenes
4
Bainbridge Beverage West, LLC
Juice HACCP/CGMP for Foods/Adulterated/Insanitary Conditions
5
VapeL1FE, LLC
Family Smoking Prevention and Tobacco Control Act/Adulterated/Misbranded
6
Mike Millenkamp Dairy Cattle

7
Empowered Diagnostics LLC
Unapproved Products Related to the Coronavirus Disease 2019 (COVID-19)
8
RoyalVibe Health Ltd.
CGMP/QSR/Medical Devices/PMA/Adulterated/Misbranded
9
Land View, Inc.
CGMP/Medicated Feeds/Adulterated
10
Green Pharmaceuticals Inc.

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

none selenium solution:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd


PAGE_LENGHT = 50


def get_letters(page: int):
    start = page * PAGE_LENGHT
    url = f"https://www.fda.gov/datatables/views/ajax?field_letter_issue_datetime=All&field_change_date_2=All&draw={page}&columns%5B0%5D%5Bdata%5D=0&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B0%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B1%5D%5Bdata%5D=1&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B1%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B2%5D%5Bdata%5D=2&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B2%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B3%5D%5Bdata%5D=3&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B3%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B4%5D%5Bdata%5D=4&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B4%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B5%5D%5Bdata%5D=5&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B5%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B6%5D%5Bdata%5D=6&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B6%5D%5Borderable%5D=true&columns%5B6%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&columns%5B7%5D%5Bdata%5D=7&columns%5B7%5D%5Bname%5D=&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearchable%5D=true&columns%5B7%5D%5Borderable%5D=false&columns%5B7%5D%5Bsearch%5D%5Bregex%5D=false&start={start}&length={PAGE_LENGHT}&search%5Bregex%5D=false&_drupal_ajax=1&_wrapper_format=drupal_ajax&view_base_path=inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations%2Fcompliance-actions-and-activities%2Fwarning-letters%2Fdatatables-data&view_display_id=warning_letter_solr_block&view_dom_id=4605f153788b3a17043d0e031eb733846503177581602cd9fd58ecd78629801b&view_name=warning_letter_solr_index&view_path=%2Finspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations%2Fcompliance-actions-and-activities%2Fwarning-letters&total_items=3433"
    letters = []
    for letter in requests.get(url).json()['data']:
        letters.append([BeautifulSoup(row, 'lxml').get_text(strip=True) for row in letter])
    return letters


result = []
for i in range(0, 5):
    result += get_letters(i)
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
print(df)
```

OUTPUT:

```
              0           1                              2  ... 5  6  7 
0    12/27/2022  11/07/2022                Land View, Inc.  ...         
1    12/27/2022  11/22/2022  MD Pharmaceutical Supply, LLC  ...         
2    12/27/2022  06/01/2022    Supreme Fruit Produce, Inc.  ...         
3    12/27/2022  10/06/2022      Empowered Diagnostics LLC  ...         
4    12/27/2022  11/18/2022          RoyalVibe Health Ltd.  ...         
..          ...         ...                            ...  ... .. .. ..
245  08/11/2022  08/11/2022                  The Juice Bar  ...         
246  08/09/2022  06/16/2022                 InfuTronix LLC  ...         
247  08/09/2022  07/12/2022               Zyno Medical LLC  ...         
248  08/09/2022  07/28/2022                Vitti Labs, LLC  ...         
249  08/09/2022  07/22/2022              Muscle Feast, LLC  ...
```

**UPDATE**

to find request use dev tools(f12 default in chrome)
[image]

now we need to figure out how to work with this data, this is a simple html text, and bs4 will help us with this. If link needed u can change `letters.append` to

```
letters.append({
    'Posted Date': BeautifulSoup(letter[0], 'lxml').get_text(strip=True),
    'Letter Issue Date': BeautifulSoup(letter[1], 'lxml').get_text(strip=True),
    'Company Name': BeautifulSoup(letter[2], 'lxml').get_text(strip=True),
    'Issuing Office': BeautifulSoup(letter[3], 'lxml').get_text(strip=True),
    'Subject': BeautifulSoup(letter[4], 'lxml').get_text(strip=True),
    'Link': 'https://www.fda.gov/' + BeautifulSoup(letter[2], 'lxml').find('a').get('href'),
})
```

And new output looks like:

```
   Posted Date Letter Issue Date                                                                                      Company Name                                                Issuing Office                                                                                      Subject                                                                                                                                                                                                  Link
0   12/27/2022        11/07/2022                                                                                   Land View, Inc.          Division of Human and Animal Food Operations West VI                                                             CGMP/Medicated Feeds/Adulterated                                                                     https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/land-view-inc-638704-11072022
1   12/27/2022        11/22/2022                                                                     MD Pharmaceutical Supply, LLC               Division of Pharmaceutical Quality Operations I                                      CGMP/Active Pharmaceutical Ingredient (API)/Adulterated                                                      https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/md-pharmaceutical-supply-llc-637815-11222022
2   12/27/2022        06/01/2022                                                                       Supreme Fruit Produce, Inc.                                 Division of Southwest Imports                                                 Foreign Supplier Verification Program (FSVP)                                                         https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/supreme-fruit-produce-inc-631972-06012022
3   12/27/2022        10/06/2022                                                                         Empowered Diagnostics LLC                    Center for Devices and Radiological Health                       Unapproved Products Related to the Coronavirus Disease 2019 (COVID-19)                                                         https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/empowered-diagnostics-llc-638164-10062022
4   12/27/2022        11/18/2022                                                                             RoyalVibe Health Ltd.                    Center for Devices and Radiological Health                                          CGMP/QSR/Medical Devices/PMA/Adulterated/Misbranded                                                              https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/royalvibe-health-ltd-639553-11182022
5   12/27/2022        11/28/2022                                                                     Bainbridge Beverage West, LLC           Division of Human and Animal Food Operations West V                                 Juice HACCP/CGMP for Foods/Adulterated/Insanitary Conditions                                                      https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/bainbridge-beverage-west-llc-638942-11282022
6   12/27/2022        12/16/2022                                                                        Green Pharmaceuticals Inc.              Division of Pharmaceutical Quality Operations IV                                                                     Drug Product/Adulterated                                                         https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/green-pharmaceuticals-inc-635162-12162022
7   12/27/2022        12/16/2022                                                                                     VapeL1FE, LLC                                   Center for Tobacco Products                     Family Smoking Prevention and Tobacco Control Act/Adulterated/Misbranded                                                                      https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/vapel1fe-llc-648624-12162022
8   12/27/2022        12/09/2022                                                                       Ruth Special Food Store LLC                                 Division of Northeast Imports                                                 Foreign Supplier Verification Program (FSVP)                                                       https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/ruth-special-food-store-llc-644551-12092022
9   12/27/2022        11/28/2022                                                                      Mike Millenkamp Dairy Cattle          Division of Human and Animal Food Operations West II                                                                  New Animal Drug/Adulterated                                                      https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/mike-millenkamp-dairy-cattle-640782-11282022
10  12/27/2022        11/10/2022                                                            EarthLab, Inc., dba Wise Woman Herbals          Division of Human and Animal Food Operations West VI                                               CGMP/Dietary Supplement/Adulterated/Misbranded                                               https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/earthlab-inc-dba-wise-woman-herbals-634872-11102022
11  12/27/2022        12/09/2022                                                                Big Olaf Creamery LLC dba Big Olaf          Division of Human and Animal Food Operations East IV  CGMP/Food/Prepared, Packed or Held Under Insanitary Conditions/Adulterated/L. monocytogenes                                                https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/big-olaf-creamery-llc-dba-big-olaf-642758-12092022
12  12/22/2022        12/22/2022                                                                                      BS Vapes LLC                                   Center for Tobacco Products                     Family Smoking Prevention and Tobacco Control Act/Adulterated/Misbranded                                                                      https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/bs-vapes-llc-647308-12222022
13  12/22/2022        12/22/2022                                                JP & SN Enterprises Inc. d/b/a eCigs International                                   Center for Tobacco Products                     Family Smoking Prevention and Tobacco Control Act/Adulterated/Misbranded                                     https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/jp-sn-enterprises-inc-dba-ecigs-international-647315-12222022
14  12/20/2022        11/08/2022                                                                                 Dollar Tree, Inc.  Office of Human and Animal Food Operations – West Division 3                                                         Interstate Commerce/Food/Adulterated                                                                   https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/dollar-tree-inc-629509-11082022
15  12/20/2022        07/27/2022                                                                      Sagent Pharmaceuticals, Inc.                  Division Pharmaceutical Quality Operations I                                                                       CGMP/Drugs/Adulterated                                                        https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/sagent-pharmaceuticals-inc-636636-07272022
16  12/20/2022        11/21/2022                                                                           Nature’s Way Farms, LLC                                 Division of Southwest Imports                                                 Foreign Supplier Verification Program (FSVP)                                                             https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/natures-way-farms-llc-641201-11212022
17  12/20/2022        12/08/2022                                                                                 Nortec Quimica SA                Center for Drug Evaluation and Research | CDER                                      CGMP/Active Pharmaceutical Ingredient (API)/Adulterated                                                                 https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/nortec-quimica-sa-639894-12082022
18  12/20/2022        11/30/2022                                                                         CHS Inc./CHS River Plains           Division of Human and Animal Food Operations West I                                                             CGMP/Medicated Feeds/Adulterated                                                           https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/chs-incchs-river-plains-642790-11302022
19  12/20/2022        12/02/2022                                                                         DuPont Nutrition USA Inc.               Division of Pharmaceutical Quality Operations I                                                               CGMP/Drug Products/Adulterated                                                          https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/dupont-nutrition-usa-inc-627211-12022022
20  12/20/2022        11/01/2022                                                                            Del Valle Import Corp.                                 Division of Northeast Imports                                                 Foreign Supplier Verification Program (FSVP)                                                             https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/del-valle-import-corp-642784-11012022
21  12/20/2022        08/25/2022                                                                                   Sree Nidhi Corp          Center for Food Safety and Applied Nutrition (CFSAN)                                                 Foreign Supplier Verification Program (FSVP)                                                                   https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/sree-nidhi-corp-634266-08252022
22  12/20/2022        12/14/2022                                                                              Adarsh Daswani, M.D.                Center for Drug Evaluation and Research | CDER                                                                        Clinical Investigator                                                                 https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/adarsh-daswani-md-648606-12142022
23  12/15/2022        12/15/2022                                                                                    Vape King Inc.                                   Center for Tobacco Products                     Family Smoking Prevention and Tobacco Control Act/Adulterated/Misbranded                                                                     https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/vape-king-inc-646625-12152022
24  12/15/2022        12/15/2022                                                                         Vapor E-Cigarette, L.L.C.                                   Center for Tobacco Products                     Family Smoking Prevention and Tobacco Control Act/Adulterated/Misbranded                                                             https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/vapor-e-cigarette-llc-646876-12152022
25  12/13/2022        12/02/2022                                                                      SV3, LLC d/b/a Mi-One Brands                                   Center for Tobacco Products                     Family Smoking Prevention and Tobacco Control Act/Adulterated/Misbranded                                                         https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/sv3-llc-dba-mi-one-brands-647624-12022022
26  12/13/2022        12/07/2022                                                   Centrient Pharmaceuticals India Private Limited                Center for Drug Evaluation and Research | CDER                                      CGMP/Active Pharmaceutical Ingredient (API)/Adulterated                                   https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/centrient-pharmaceuticals-india-private-limited-640196-12072022
27  12/13/2022        11/22/2022                                                                                   Cecilia Alvarez                                 Division of Southwest Imports                                                 Foreign Supplier Verification Program (FSVP)                                                                   https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/cecilia-alvarez-643706-11222022
28  12/13/2022        11/29/2022                                                                         Gobwa Exotic Imports Inc.                                 Division of Northeast Imports                                                 Foreign Supplier Verification Program (FSVP)                                                          https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/gobwa-exotic-imports-inc-641031-11292022
29  12/13/2022        12/05/2022  Thriftmaster Texas, LLC. d/b/a ThriftMaster Global Holdings, Inc. and TM Global Biosciences, LLC                Center for Drug Evaluation and Research | CDER              Finished Pharmaceuticals/Unapproved New Drug/Misbranded/Adulterated Human Foods  https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/thriftmaster-texas-llc-dba-thriftmaster-global-holdings-inc-and-tm-global-biosciences-llc-641057
30  12/13/2022        11/21/2022                                                                          Euphoria Fancy Food Inc.                                 Division of Northeast Imports                                                 Foreign Supplier Verification Program (FSVP)                                                           https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/euphoria-fancy-food-inc-641801-11212022
31  12/08/2022        12/08/2022                                                                                  Cloud House Vape                                   Center for Tobacco Products                     Family Smoking Prevention and Tobacco Control Act/Adulterated/Misbranded                                                                  https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/cloud-house-vape-647544-12082022
32  12/08/2022        12/08/2022                                                          Vapors of Ohio Inc d/b/a Nostalgic Vapes                                   Center for Tobacco Products                     Family Smoking Prevention and Tobacco Control Act/Adulterated/Misbranded                                               https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/vapors-ohio-inc-dba-nostalgic-vapes-644739-12082022
33  12/06/2022        11/28/2022                                                                                   AG Hair Limited                Center for Drug Evaluation and Research | CDER                                                    CGMP/Finished Pharmaceuticals/Adulterated                                                                   https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/ag-hair-limited-638646-11282022
34  12/06/2022        11/22/2022                                                                  Glenmark Pharmaceuticals Limited                Center for Drug Evaluation and Research | CDER                                                    CGMP/Finished Pharmaceuticals/Adulterated                                                  https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/glenmark-pharmaceuticals-limited-637314-11222022
35  12/06/2022        09/23/2022                                                                                   Saffron USA LLC          Division of Human and Animal Food Operations East IV                                                              Unapproved New Drugs/Misbranded                                                                   https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/saffron-usa-llc-629821-09232022
36  12/06/2022        10/24/2022                                                                       Cryos International USA LLC                  Division of Biological Products Operations I             Deviations/CFR/Regulations for Human Cells, Tissues & Cellular Products (HCT/Ps)                                                       https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/cryos-international-usa-llc-639696-10242022
37  12/06/2022        10/17/2022                                                                           Zuland Distributor Corp                                 Division of Southwest Imports                                                 Foreign Supplier Verification Program (FSVP)                                                           https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/zuland-distributor-corp-638899-10172022
38  12/06/2022        11/07/2022                                                                                  Manzela USA, LLC                                 Division of Southwest Imports                                                 Foreign Supplier Verification Program (FSVP)                                                                   https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/manzela-usa-llc-642268-11072022
39  12/06/2022        11/07/2022                                                                       Maliba African Market Corp.                                 Division of Northeast Imports                                                 Foreign Supplier Verification Program (FSVP)                                                        https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/maliba-african-market-corp-642698-11072022
40  12/06/2022        11/30/2022                                                                                    Kari Gran Inc.              Division of Pharmaceutical Quality Operations IV                                                    CGMP/Finished Pharmaceuticals/Adulterated                                                                     https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/kari-gran-inc-640035-11302022
41  12/01/2022        12/01/2022                                                               Vapor Candy Inc d/b/a The Vape Stop                                   Center for Tobacco Products                     Family Smoking Prevention and Tobacco Control Act/Adulterated/Misbranded                                                     https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/vapor-candy-inc-dba-vape-stop-645475-12012022
42  11/30/2022        11/30/2022                                                                              Jayde's Vapor Lounge                                   Center for Tobacco Products                     Family Smoking Prevention and Tobacco Control Act/Adulterated/Misbranded                                                               https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/jaydes-vapor-lounge-645085-11302022
43  11/29/2022        11/10/2022                                                                                 Vapor Plus OK LLC                                   Center for Tobacco Products                     Family Smoking Prevention and Tobacco Control Act/Adulterated/Misbranded                                                                 https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/vapor-plus-ok-llc-646225-11102022
44  11/29/2022        11/18/2022                                                  "David M. Lubeck, M.D./Arbor Centers for EyeCare                Center for Drug Evaluation and Research | CDER                                                              Clinical Investigator (Sponsor)                                            https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/david-m-lubeck-mdarbor-centers-eyecare-643531-11182022
45  11/29/2022        06/01/2022                                                                            Jam Jam Services, Inc.                                 Division of Southeast Imports                                                 Foreign Supplier Verification Program (FSVP)                                                              https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/jam-jam-services-inc-630847-06012022
46  11/29/2022        09/19/2022                                                                La Serranita Import and Export LLC                                 Division of Northeast Imports                                                 Foreign Supplier Verification Program (FSVP)                                                https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/la-serranita-import-and-export-llc-633743-09192022
47  11/29/2022        11/09/2022                                                                                   J R Imports LLC                                 Division of Southwest Imports                                                 Foreign Supplier Verification Program (FSVP)                                                                   https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/j-r-imports-llc-643214-11092022
48  11/29/2022        09/01/2022                                                                                   Shuzy Rock Inc.               Division of Pharmaceutical Quality Operations I                                                    CGMP/Finished Pharmaceuticals/Adulterated                                                                    https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/shuzy-rock-inc-630110-09012022
49  11/22/2022        10/19/2022                                                                                 Pepe’s Foods Inc.                                Division of West Coast Imports                                                 Foreign Supplier Verification Program (FSVP)                                                                   https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/pepes-foods-inc-640716-10192022
50  11/22/2022        11/14/2022                                                                                  yourtramadol.com                Center for Drug Evaluation and Research | CDER                                      Finished Pharmaceuticals/Unapproved New Drug/Misbranded                                                                   https://www.fda.gov//inspections-compliance-enforcement-and-criminal-investigations/warning-letters/yourtramadolcom-639959-11142022
```

Comment: This is great, can you explain a bit? For example: where did you get the url from? Also the compnay name also has a href, how do I get that? There are other columns too.

Comment: @futurenext110 I updated the answer, I hope u understan my explanation. if something is not clear, then I am ready to help